# Flip-flop logic for comparator of overcurrent detection

Tags: flipflop, orcad, over-current

I'm working on the realization of overcurrent detection that will be powered by a battery supply. I successfully simulated a comparator with an operational amplifier that will set the output high when there is overcurrent and the flip-flop circuit has to carry that value (until the reset button is pressed) and send it to the buffer that will set the MOSFET transistor on/off. I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to implement the flip-flop logic that sends the information to the buffer. Below is the schematic of my project. Thank you very much for your ideas.

[image]

Comment: Two transistor latch (bistable circuit), two NANDs, 4043 or 4044 ic (according logic), some folks even use 555. There is also possible use D flops like 4013 or 7474.

Comment: Regarding two NANDs: if possitive logic is needed (set and reset with logic High) two NORs is better option. Also two schmitt triggers will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is called "[set/reset latch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Simple_set-reset_latches)".

There are some old chips that integrate multiple latches (CD4043/CD4044, 74xx279), but the simplest solution is to build a latch with two NAND or NOR gates ((SN)74xx2G00, (SN)74xx2G02):

[image: S/R NAND latch]
<sup>(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Simple_set-reset_latches))</sup>

To ensure that it is in the correct state after power up, you need a reset signal during power up.

Comment: I have created the schematic for the latch, but how do I convert the overvoltage value which is over 12V from the output of my comparator as "HIGH" value to the NOR gate? Below are pictures of the schematic and simulation.  
Schematic: https://imgur.com/tJRvY96
Simulation: https://imgur.com/FeuFFjW

Comment: Just adjust the pull-up resistor at the comparator's output. Which you forgot. (How an open-collector output works and how to do level shifting with it is a different question.)

Comment: I adjusted the pull-up resistor but the latch circuit still does not work. Is the value of the resistor wrong? https://imgur.com/lAJEUC9

Comment: This is not a pull-up resistor. Look up how open-collector outputs work, and if needed, ask a new question.